# CKEditor 4 combinate css

Tags: css, ckeditor

I use CSS on my website to style the items.

In my (own developed) CMS I use CKEditor as WYSIWYG-editor.

I would like the editor to have the same style as the content on my webpage.
The CSS of my page looks like this:

```
.content 
{
    ...
}
.content ul, .content ol 
{
    ...
}
.content p
{
    ...
}
```

But the stylesheet of CKEditor (contents.css) looks like this:

```
body
{
    ...
}
ol,ul,dl
{
    ...
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to make this in to one stylesheet, or to edit CKEditor, so a div.content is added?

---

I found the answer, change config.js to:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.bodyClass = 'content'; //class that body needs to refer to
    config.contentsCss = '/css/beheer.css'; //your stylesheet
```

Comment: Please mark your problem as solved once you find the solution to let other people know there's nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I edited on the startpost, I found the answer myself:

Change config.js to:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.bodyClass = 'content'; //class that body needs to refer to
    config.contentsCss = '/css/beheer.css'; //your stylesheet
```

Answer (score 0):

In **CKEDITOR**, you write a `<div>` tag for any of your `ol,ul,dl,h1,etc` elements..

Just go to source code button in **CKEDITOR** and then you can edit the way you want.